# MVC RegisterRoutes to change just the controller name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

We have an MVC 4 application with two different roles, All the requests to Role1 is forwarded to

Role1XYZController and Role2 requests are forwarded to Role2XYZContoller.

Request url for these page should appear as: XYZController/Index in the browser.

We can achieve this using :

```
if(role == role1)
{
routes.MapRoute(
    "XYZRoute",                                              // Route name
    "XYZ/Request",                          
    new { controller = "Role1XYZ", action = "Request", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  
);
}
```

But I have multiple action methods: Request, Save, Drilldown, Details in Role1XYZ controller. Should I create separate MapRoute for all the actionMethods?

How can we reroute just the controller name in request url?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `Request` with `{action}`:

```
if(role == role1)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "XYZRoute",                                              // Route name
        "XYZ/{action}",                          
        new { controller = "Role1XYZ", action = "Request", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  
    );
}
```

Remember, the last line is just the defaults for the route. It will still match the other actions.